# CSS media query. Strange width bug

Tags: css, mobile

I'm developing a relatively simple website using a media query to target mobile devices (640px width and under) and when I view it on my archaic iPhone 3g it looks fine apart from the fact that there seems to be something that makes it primarily appear very "zoomed out"

It's probably easier to show you an example;

http://deanelliott.me/misc/berman/interior.php

I've only tested it on my iPhone so I'm not sure how it displays on other phones.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Show some CSS, I am too lazy to look at the site and get the CSS myself...

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XGmRx/2/) here's the entire stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your viewport settings are missing.

This is what I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: The target-density bit threw up an error for me, but I jut replaced it with maximum-scale=1 and it worked like a charm. Thanks